# why doesn't the value of a variable change if it consist of an incremented number?

Tags: python

I have a variable that is supposed to show the sum of two numbers.When i try to increment one of the numbers the sum remains the same, however the number has been incremented.

```
x = 1

test = 0 + x

while x <= 5:
    print('the result is',test)
    x+=1
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
the result is 1
the result is 2
the result is 3
the result is 4
the result is 5
```

but instead i get:

```
the result is 1
the result is 1
the result is 1
the result is 1
the result is 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: after you do `test = 0 + x` the variable `test` gets a value. It doesn't know that if you change `x` it should be changed as well... why do you even need `test`?

Comment: Put `test` inside your loop and it should work

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? It shows a good amount of code, MCVE, and received/expected output, and clearly states the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a variable with an expression just copies the value of the expression, it doesn't make the variable always re-evaluate that expression.

If you want something that re-calculates, use a function.

```
x = 1
test = lambda: 0 + x

while x <= 5:
    print('The result is', test())
    x += 1
```

Or you can put the assignment inside the loop:

```
x = 1

while x <= 5:
    test = 0 + x
    print('The result is', test)
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting `test` to change each time you change `x`, but that's not how variables work. Once you assign a value to a variable, it will not change (except for mutable objects like arrays, but that's not what we're dealing with here). You should print `test` instead of `x`, or reassign the `test` variable as well.

Your code should be:

```py
x = 1

test = 0 + x

while x <= 5:
    print('the result is', x) # modified line
    x+=1
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking. They're wanting a way to have one variable reference another and have both variables change when the references one is changed. (Consider a language like C++ where you could use pointers to accomplish the task). Edit: Your edit addressed the OP's actual concern

Comment: This was not really clear. Closest thing to assigning a pointer looks like `test = x` not `test = 0 + x`. But until, the OP edit its post, I am not sure about what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusion 2 things.

The line `test = 0 + x` is not an equation. It's not like math where `y = mx + n` and `y` is getting multiple values for each `x`.

This line is an assignment. Meaning that `test` is getting the value of `0+x` which is `0+1` which is `1`, so after the program assigning the value of `x` and computing the right side of the assignment you are getting `test=1` and that's it.

This is how programming works. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the placement of the lines and the [order of execution](http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch03.html), `test = 0 + x` runs and `test` stores the value and becomes a int value. In the `while` loop just prints the value, `x` has no efect on it.

One way to fix this is to make test a function.

```
def test(value): 
    new_value = 0 + value
    return new_value

x = 1
while x <= 5:
    print('the result is', test(x))
    x += 1
```

Or make the loop execute each time the line.

```
x = 1

while x <= 5:
    test = 0 + x
    print('the result is', test)
    x += 1
```